# Subfolder as root element in CSS

Tags: html, css, url

I have web application located at *http://{some-domain}.com/SubFolder* - so this address can be considered as root folder.

But when I am trying to set image URL in CSS

```
background-image: url( "img/logo.png" );
```

and access application *http://{some-domain}.com/SubFolder* then image address is interpreted as

*http://{some-domain}.com/img/logo.png*

instead of

*http://{some-domain}.com/SubFolder/img/logo.png*

The "SubFolder" part of path is skipped, so image could not be found. Are there any way to resolve this issue without using JS or server-side logic? I am unable to specify image URL as

```
background-image: url( "SubFolder/img/logo.png" );
```

because this "SubFolder" part is about to change and should not be hardcoded.

Comment: Where is background-image: url( "img/logo.png" ); used ? embedded in http://some-domain.com/SubFolder/index.html or in http://some-domain.com/style.css ? thank you to give this precision.

Comment: It is used at page itself, not in .css file. Also there is no .html in address, it is route of MVC controller, so URL will be http://some-domain.com/SubFolder

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
background-image: url( "../img/logo.png" );
```